# SQL Query 2 tables null results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was asked this question in an interview: 
From the 2 tables below, write a query to pull customers with no sales orders.
How many ways to write this query and which would have best performance.

- Table 1: `Customer`  - `CustomerID`
- Table 2: `SalesOrder` - `OrderID, CustomerID, OrderDate`

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer C
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN SalesOrder SO ON C.CustomerID = SO.CustomerID
WHERE SO.OrderID = NULL
```

Is my query correct and are there other ways to write the query and get the same results?

Comment: And for which **concrete database** is this? SQL is just the **query language** used by many databases - which one are you using? MySQL? POstgres? Oracle? SQL Server? IBM DB2? Something else entirely? Please update your tags accordingly!

Comment: Performance wise i have no idea but another way in sql server might be `Select CustomerID from Customer c where CustomerID NOT in (Select Distinct CustomerID from SalesOrder)` but i assume you would have to take a look at the query plans sql server creates for both queries.
Also you might find more answers at the database site from stackexchange.

Comment: `SO.OrderID = NULL` will not do what you think it will.  The correct syntax is `SO.OrderID is NULL`

Comment: There is no way to answer the performance question without knowing the entire schema and testing it.  The answer I would look for in an interview is "blah blah blah **but I would need to do some performance testing with your schema and data to be sure**" or "It depends".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answering for MySQL instead of SQL Server, cause you tagged it later with SQL Server, so I thought (since this was an interview question, that it wouldn't bother you, for which DBMS this is). Note though, that the queries I wrote are standard sql, they should run in every RDBMS out there. How each RDBMS handles those queries is another issue, though.*

I wrote this little procedure for you, to have a test case. It creates the tables customers and orders like you specified and I added primary keys and foreign keys, like one would usually do it. No other indexes, as every column worth indexing here is already primary key. 250 customers are created, 100 of them made an order (though out of convenience none of them twice / multiple times). A dump of the data follows, posted the script just in case you want to play around a little by increasing the numbers.

```
delimiter $$
create procedure fill_table()
begin
create table customers(customerId int primary key) engine=innodb;
set @x = 1;
while (@x <= 250) do
insert into customers values(@x);
set @x := @x + 1;
end while;

create table orders(orderId int auto_increment primary key,
customerId int,
orderDate timestamp,
foreign key fk_customer (customerId) references customers(customerId)
) engine=innodb;

insert into orders(customerId, orderDate)
select
customerId,
now() - interval customerId day
from
customers
order by rand()
limit 100;

end $$
delimiter ;

call fill_table();
```

For me, this resulted in this:

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `customerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customerId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `customers` VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30),(31),(32),(33),(34),(35),(36),(37),(38),(39),(40),(41),(42),(43),(44),(45),(46),(47),(48),(49),(50),(51),(52),(53),(54),(55),(56),(57),(58),(59),(60),(61),(62),(63),(64),(65),(66),(67),(68),(69),(70),(71),(72),(73),(74),(75),(76),(77),(78),(79),(80),(81),(82),(83),(84),(85),(86),(87),(88),(89),(90),(91),(92),(93),(94),(95),(96),(97),(98),(99),(100),(101),(102),(103),(104),(105),(106),(107),(108),(109),(110),(111),(112),(113),(114),(115),(116),(117),(118),(119),(120),(121),(122),(123),(124),(125),(126),(127),(128),(129),(130),(131),(132),(133),(134),(135),(136),(137),(138),(139),(140),(141),(142),(143),(144),(145),(146),(147),(148),(149),(150),(151),(152),(153),(154),(155),(156),(157),(158),(159),(160),(161),(162),(163),(164),(165),(166),(167),(168),(169),(170),(171),(172),(173),(174),(175),(176),(177),(178),(179),(180),(181),(182),(183),(184),(185),(186),(187),(188),(189),(190),(191),(192),(193),(194),(195),(196),(197),(198),(199),(200),(201),(202),(203),(204),(205),(206),(207),(208),(209),(210),(211),(212),(213),(214),(215),(216),(217),(218),(219),(220),(221),(222),(223),(224),(225),(226),(227),(228),(229),(230),(231),(232),(233),(234),(235),(236),(237),(238),(239),(240),(241),(242),(243),(244),(245),(246),(247),(248),(249),(250);

CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `orderId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customerId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orderDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orderId`),
  KEY `fk_customer` (`customerId`),
  CONSTRAINT `orders_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customerId`) REFERENCES `customers` (`customerId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=128 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `orders` VALUES (1,247,'2013-06-24 19:50:07'),(2,217,'2013-07-24 19:50:07'),(3,8,'2014-02-18 20:50:07'),(4,40,'2014-01-17 20:50:07'),(5,52,'2014-01-05 20:50:07'),(6,80,'2013-12-08 20:50:07'),(7,169,'2013-09-10 19:50:07'),(8,135,'2013-10-14 19:50:07'),(9,115,'2013-11-03 20:50:07'),(10,225,'2013-07-16 19:50:07'),(11,112,'2013-11-06 20:50:07'),(12,243,'2013-06-28 19:50:07'),(13,158,'2013-09-21 19:50:07'),(14,24,'2014-02-02 20:50:07'),(15,214,'2013-07-27 19:50:07'),(16,25,'2014-02-01 20:50:07'),(17,245,'2013-06-26 19:50:07'),(18,182,'2013-08-28 19:50:07'),(19,166,'2013-09-13 19:50:07'),(20,69,'2013-12-19 20:50:07'),(21,85,'2013-12-03 20:50:07'),(22,44,'2014-01-13 20:50:07'),(23,103,'2013-11-15 20:50:07'),(24,19,'2014-02-07 20:50:07'),(25,33,'2014-01-24 20:50:07'),(26,102,'2013-11-16 20:50:07'),(27,41,'2014-01-16 20:50:07'),(28,94,'2013-11-24 20:50:07'),(29,43,'2014-01-14 20:50:07'),(30,150,'2013-09-29 19:50:07'),(31,218,'2013-07-23 19:50:07'),(32,131,'2013-10-18 19:50:07'),(33,77,'2013-12-11 20:50:07'),(34,2,'2014-02-24 20:50:07'),(35,45,'2014-01-12 20:50:07'),(36,230,'2013-07-11 19:50:07'),(37,101,'2013-11-17 20:50:07'),(38,31,'2014-01-26 20:50:07'),(39,56,'2014-01-01 20:50:07'),(40,176,'2013-09-03 19:50:07'),(41,223,'2013-07-18 19:50:07'),(42,145,'2013-10-04 19:50:07'),(43,26,'2014-01-31 20:50:07'),(44,62,'2013-12-26 20:50:07'),(45,195,'2013-08-15 19:50:07'),(46,153,'2013-09-26 19:50:07'),(47,179,'2013-08-31 19:50:07'),(48,104,'2013-11-14 20:50:07'),(49,7,'2014-02-19 20:50:07'),(50,209,'2013-08-01 19:50:07'),(51,86,'2013-12-02 20:50:07'),(52,110,'2013-11-08 20:50:07'),(53,204,'2013-08-06 19:50:07'),(54,187,'2013-08-23 19:50:07'),(55,114,'2013-11-04 20:50:07'),(56,38,'2014-01-19 20:50:07'),(57,236,'2013-07-05 19:50:07'),(58,79,'2013-12-09 20:50:07'),(59,96,'2013-11-22 20:50:07'),(60,37,'2014-01-20 20:50:07'),(61,207,'2013-08-03 19:50:07'),(62,22,'2014-02-04 20:50:07'),(63,120,'2013-10-29 20:50:07'),(64,200,'2013-08-10 19:50:07'),(65,51,'2014-01-06 20:50:07'),(66,181,'2013-08-29 19:50:07'),(67,4,'2014-02-22 20:50:07'),(68,123,'2013-10-26 19:50:07'),(69,108,'2013-11-10 20:50:07'),(70,55,'2014-01-02 20:50:07'),(71,76,'2013-12-12 20:50:07'),(72,6,'2014-02-20 20:50:07'),(73,18,'2014-02-08 20:50:07'),(74,211,'2013-07-30 19:50:07'),(75,53,'2014-01-04 20:50:07'),(76,216,'2013-07-25 19:50:07'),(77,32,'2014-01-25 20:50:07'),(78,74,'2013-12-14 20:50:07'),(79,138,'2013-10-11 19:50:07'),(80,197,'2013-08-13 19:50:07'),(81,221,'2013-07-20 19:50:07'),(82,118,'2013-10-31 20:50:07'),(83,61,'2013-12-27 20:50:07'),(84,28,'2014-01-29 20:50:07'),(85,16,'2014-02-10 20:50:07'),(86,39,'2014-01-18 20:50:07'),(87,3,'2014-02-23 20:50:07'),(88,46,'2014-01-11 20:50:07'),(89,189,'2013-08-21 19:50:07'),(90,59,'2013-12-29 20:50:07'),(91,249,'2013-06-22 19:50:07'),(92,127,'2013-10-22 19:50:07'),(93,47,'2014-01-10 20:50:07'),(94,178,'2013-09-01 19:50:07'),(95,141,'2013-10-08 19:50:07'),(96,188,'2013-08-22 19:50:07'),(97,220,'2013-07-21 19:50:07'),(98,15,'2014-02-11 20:50:07'),(99,175,'2013-09-04 19:50:07'),(100,206,'2013-08-04 19:50:07');
```

Okay, now to the queries. Three ways came to my mind, I omitted the `right join` that MDiesel did, because it's actually just another way of writing `left join`. It was invented for lazy sql developers, that don't want to switch table names, but instead just rewrite one word.

Anyway, first query:

```
select
c.*
from
customers c
left join orders o on c.customerId = o.customerId
where o.customerId is null;
```

Results in an execution plan like this:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref              | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | index | NULL          | PRIMARY     | 4       | NULL             |  250 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | o     | ref   | fk_customer   | fk_customer | 5       | wtf.c.customerId |    1 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------------------+------+--------------------------+
```

---

Second query:

```
select
c.*
from
customers c
where c.customerId not in (select distinct customerId from orders);
```

Results in an execution plan like this:

```
+----+--------------------+--------+----------------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table  | type           | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+--------+----------------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | c      | index          | NULL          | PRIMARY     | 4       | NULL |  250 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | orders | index_subquery | fk_customer   | fk_customer | 5       | func |    2 | Using index              |
+----+--------------------+--------+----------------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

---

Third query:

```
select
c.*
from
customers c
where not exists (select 1 from orders o where o.customerId = c.customerId);
```

Results in an execution plan like this:

```
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref              | rows | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | c     | index | NULL          | PRIMARY     | 4       | NULL             |  250 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | o     | ref   | fk_customer   | fk_customer | 5       | wtf.c.customerId |    1 | Using where; Using index |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------------------+------+--------------------------+
```

---

We can see in all execution plans, that the customers table is read as a whole, but from the index (the implicit one as the only column is primary key). This may change, when you select other columns from the table, that are not in an index.

The first one seems to be the best. For each row in customers only one row in orders is read. The `id` column suggests, that MySQL can do this in one step, as only indexes are involved.

The second query seems to be the worst (though all 3 queries shouldn't perform too bad). For each row in customers the subquery is executed (the select_type column tells this).

The third query is not much different in that it uses a dependent subquery, but should perform better than the second query. Explaining the small differences would lead to far now. If you're interested, here's the manual page that explains what each column and their values mean here: [EXPLAIN output](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html)

**Finally:** I'd say, that the first query will perform best, but as always, in the end one has to measure, to measure and to measure.

Answer (score 1):

I can thing of two other ways to write this query:

```
SELECT C.*
FROM Customer C
LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesOrder SO ON C.CustomerID = SO.CustomerID
WHERE SO.CustomerID IS NULL

SELECT C.*
FROM Customer C
WHERE NOT C.CustomerID IN(SELECT CustomerID FROM SalesOrder)
```

Comment: I believe in your example, since you are performing a right join, that you would need your where clause to say, WHERE C.CustomerID IS NULL

Comment: I cannot say with 100% certainty, but I believe the best performance would be to start with the customers table, and left join to SalesOrder based on CustomerId (since it is the primary key in the customer's table, and a foreign key in the SalesOrders table), and finally add the where clause for SO.CustomerId being NULL

Answer (score 0):

The solutions involving outer joins will perform better than a solution using NOT IN.